# javascript display value in span tag

Tags: javascript, html

in javascript, how can i assign and display a value to `tag`, so it appears in;

`<span id=tag></span>`

This needs to be set on the pageload.

i thought it was something like:

```
<script>
document.getElementById('tag').innerHTML = 0;
</script>
```

Comment: Did you try string literal "0"?

Answer (score 3):

HTML:

```
<span id="tag"></span>
```

JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   window.onload = function(){
     var text = document.createTextNode("0");
     document.getElementById('tag').appendChild(text);
   }
</script>
```

Although it would be much easier to just do:

```
<span id="tag">0</span>
```

Comment: it doesnt display anything on pageload :o

Comment: the innerText isn't implement by other browser, what browser are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<script>
  window.onload = function(){
        document.getElementById('tag').innerHTML = 0;
  };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this also

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function myFunction() {
    var number = "0";
    document.getElementById("tag").innerHTML = number;
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="myFunction()">

<h1>"the value is: " <span id="tag"></span></h1>

</body>
</html>
```